# Building Flutter project for Android says com.android.application as not found

Tags: android, flutter, windows, gradle

I generated a new Flutter project (Flutter v3.16) in VSCode on my Windows 10 machine and then tried to run the Flutter app. I didn't make any changes to the Flutter project as I was just trying to get it to work happy path. It booted up fine as a Windows application but when I tried to boot it up on the Pixel emulator, I got the error below.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
> Settings file 'C:\Users\SFULLER01\StudioProjects\Test_flutter\android\settings.gradle' line: 26
>
> What went wrong:
> Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
>
> - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
> - Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
> - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.0')
>   Searched in the following repositories:
>   Google,
>   MavenRepo,
>   Gradle Central Plugin Repository

The Pixel emulator that I was using was `Pixel 3a API 34 extension level 7 x86 64 (mobile)`. It's just the Android emulator that came with Android Studio when I installed it.

I thought maybe the issue was with Visual Studio Code, so I tried generating a new Flutter project with Android Studio (Giraffe), but I got the same error.

Maybe this is an issue with the Android Studio gradle version and the version of Gradle that Flutter is expecting? I don't know. If it is, I'm not sure how to go about resolving this issue.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
plugin{

 id "com.android.application"

}
```

instead of this

```
plugin{

id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false

}
```

Note make this changes in app level gradle file

> project/android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Hello, that actually didn't work. "com.android.application" was already in the app level plugins. Currently I have "com.android.application" in my app/build.gradle AND "com.android.applcation" in settings.gradle. Did I miss something?

Comment: You don't need com.android.application in settings.gradle

Comment: See this issue for more info and correct setup: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135392